Gravitational time dilation in uniformly accelerated rocket and cosmological expansion
I was wondering if, in the relativistic rocket trip problem, we should also consider the gravitational time delay formula in the calculations for the observer in the rocket, i.e., if, beyond the formula relating acceleration and proper time
$$a=\dfrac{c}{\tau}\cosh^{-1}\left(1+\dfrac{d\tau^2}{c^2}\right)$$
Equivalence principle suggests that this a equals the gravitational g, so we do not need to consider the gravitational time dilation effect, but I am not sure if I am correct. In addition to that, how the cosmological acceleration related to $\Lambda$ modifies the proper time-acceleration formula above too, since there is an extra contribution of the expanding spacetime?

Have you tried deriving the Lorentz factor in Schwarzschild spacetime?
